# How to implement convolutional neural networks with exponentialled decayed learning rates in Keras or Theano

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, keras

I want to implement convolutional neural networks (CNN) with exponentially decayed learning rate in Keras or Theano. The learning rate is dynamically changed according to the following update law:

```
eta = et0*exp(LossFunction)
where et0 is the initial learning rate and LossFunction is a cost function
```

I know Keras allows for setup the SGD optimizer:

```
SGD(lr, momentum0, decay, nesterov)
```

The decay term only allows for a fixed decayed Learning rate decay over each epoch.

How to set up or code the SGD using a learning rate that is exponentially decayed with respect to the cost function? For you information, I post the source code of SGD in Keras:

```
class SGD(Optimizer):

'''Stochastic gradient descent, with support for momentum,
learning rate decay, and Nesterov momentum.


# Arguments
    lr: float >= 0. Learning rate.
    momentum: float >= 0. Parameter updates momentum.
    decay: float >= 0. Learning rate decay over each update.
    nesterov: boolean. Whether to apply Nesterov momentum.
'''

def __init__(self, lr=0.01, momentum=0., decay=0.,

             nesterov=False, **kwargs):

    super(SGD, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.__dict__.update(locals())
    self.iterations = K.variable(0.)
    self.lr = K.variable(lr)
    self.momentum = K.variable(momentum)
    self.decay = K.variable(decay)
    self.inital_decay = decay

def get_updates(self, params, constraints, loss):
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
    self.updates = []

    lr = self.lr
    if self.inital_decay > 0:
        lr *= (1. / (1. + self.decay * self.iterations))
        self.updates .append(K.update_add(self.iterations, 1))

    # momentum
    shapes = [K.get_variable_shape(p) for p in params]
    moments = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]
    self.weights = [self.iterations] + moments

    for p, g, m in zip(params, grads, moments):
        v = self.momentum * m - lr * g  # velocity
        self.updates.append(K.update(m, v))

        if self.nesterov:
            new_p = p + self.momentum * v - lr * g
        else:
            new_p = p + v

        # apply constraints
        if p in constraints:
            c = constraints[p]
            new_p = c(new_p)

        self.updates.append(K.update(p, new_p))
    return self.updates

def get_config(self):
    config = {'lr': float(K.get_value(self.lr)),
              'momentum': float(K.get_value(self.momentum)),
              'decay': float(K.get_value(self.decay)),
              'nesterov': self.nesterov}

    base_config = super(SGD, self).get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could get the behaviour using the following schema:

1. Create a new learning rate controler class using [this](https://keras.io/callbacks/#learningratescheduler).
2. Make it constructor to accept the training set and starting learning rate when provided to `fit` method.
3. Make it to compute the loss after every epoch and update learning rate.

Comment: Your suggestion seems a good idea. But I check in LearningRateScheduler(schedule), the schedule function only accept an epoch index as input. The question is how to incorporate loss information in the framework of LearningRateScheduler

Comment: you could make fields in your class which would store datasets and model and in each iteration you would compute appropriate statistics using them.

Answer (score 1):

Keras has an inbuilt function for scheduling the learning rate. You can look in the Keras callback documentation from [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/). Here is an example:

```
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
```

LearningRateScheduler(schedule) function takes one input called scheduling function.

You can define a function which will schedule the learning rate decay. This function will take epoch as an input argument. Example of step decay:

```
 def step_decay(epoch):
     initial_lrate = 0.00125
     drop = 0.5
     epochs_drop = 10.0
     lrate = initial_lrate * math.pow(drop,  
             math.floor((1+epoch)/epochs_drop))
     return lrate
```

Now use this function to create a learning rate scheduler.

`lrScheduler = LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)`

In your model.compile pass this scheduler to callback argument

```
model.compile(...,callbacks=lrScheduler,...)
```

Similarly, for exponential decay per epoch or per iteration create a function and call that function in your learning rate scheduler.

I hope this explanation will be helpful to you.